# How to do ...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE... in django

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to do the following in django's ORM?

```
INSERT INTO mytable
VALUES (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE field=4
```

I'm familiar with `get_or_create`, which takes default values, but that doesn't update the record if there are differences in the defaults. Usually I use the following approach, but it takes two queries instead of one:

```
item = Item(id=1)
item.update(**fields)
item.save()
```

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm familiar with `get_or_create`, which takes default values, but that doesn't update the record if there are differences in the defaults.

[`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) should provide the behavior you're looking for.

```
Item.objects.update_or_create(
    id=1,
    defaults=fields,
)
```

It returns the same `(object, created)` tuple as `get_or_create`.

Note that this will still perform two queries, but only in the event the record does not already exist (as is the case with `get_or_create`). If that is for some reason unacceptable, you will likely be stuck writing raw SQL to handle this, which would be unfortunate in terms of readability and maintainability.

Comment: @kungphy -- thanks for this answer. Incidentally, I also really liked your other answer (that you deleted). I'm a relatively inexperienced programmer and I was just wondering how your answer was different than my question -- it was really more a question out of curiosity than anything else. Anyways, thanks for all your help with these questions!

Answer (score 0):

I think `get_or_create()` is still the answer, but only specify the pk field(s).

```
item, _ = Item.objects.get_or_create(id=1)
item.update(**fields)
item.save()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to overwrite the special builtin `_` which gives you the last returned item...

Comment: I believe that usage of `_` only exists within interactive shells.  In module code, `_` is often used to mean "a value that I don't care about".

Comment: I remember there was another question here that was caused by the shadowing of `_` in the code, which probably was also in interactive shell only as I'm unable to reproduce it now.  Thanks for the tips.

Comment: The cases where you run a WSGI application view in the interactive interpreter and get your prompt back while still in the view's scope should be rather few.

Answer (score 0):

[Django 4.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) has added the support for `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query. It will update the fields in case the unique validation fails.

Example of above in a single query:

```py
# Let's say we have an Item model with unique on key

items = [
    Item(key='foobar', value=10),
    Item(key='foobaz', value=20),
]

# this function will create 2 rows in a single SQL query
Item.objects.bulk_create(items)

# this time it will update the value for foobar
# and create new row for barbaz
# all in a single SQL query
items = [
    Item(key='foobar', value=30),
    Item(key='barbaz', value=50),
]

Item.objects.bulk_create(
    items,
    update_conflicts=True,
    update_fields=['rate']
)
```